# Assign quarterly observations to next quarters' months

Tags: python, pandas

Consider an unbalanced panel of some variable: for each group, I observe a quarterly time-series identified by an end-of-quarter datetime object. The time-series may have holes and groups may have observations for different quarters.

My goal is, conditional on each group, to assign the end-of-quarter observations to next quarter's three months. Take, for example, the observation `4` at quarter `2009-12-31` for group `1`. I want to generate a time-series for group `1` which has observation `4` for the three months `2010-01-31, 2010-02-28, 2010-03-31`, but not for `2009-12-31`.

In my attempt, I offset end-of-quarter observations by one month, resample using 'M' and then forward fill using `ffill()`. However, that does not take care of the last quarter appropriately. Though, I could take care of the last month manually, I feel like there must be a more straight forward solution to this.

I appreciate any help.

Here's a MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
date = pd.to_datetime(['2009-12-31','2010-03-31','2010-06-30','2010-09-30','2014-03-31','2014-06-30','2015-09-30','2015-12-31','2016-03-30'])
group = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2]
variable = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
data = {'date':date, 'group':group, 'var':variable}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index(['group','date'], inplace=True)
```

Here's the input dataframe:

```
                  var
group date           
1     2009-12-31    4
      2010-03-31    5
      2010-06-30    6
      2010-09-30    7
      2014-03-31    8
      2014-06-30    9
2     2015-09-30   10
      2015-12-31   11
      2016-03-30   12
```

Here's what I expect:

```
                  var
group date           
1     2010-01-31    4
      2010-02-28    4
      2010-03-31    4
      2010-04-30    5
      2010-05-31    5
      2010-06-30    5
      2010-07-31    6
      2010-08-31    6
      2010-09-30    6
      2010-10-31    7
      2010-11-30    7
      2010-12-31    7
      2014-04-30    8
      2014-05-31    8
      2014-06-30    8
      2014-07-31    9
      2014-08-31    9
      2014-09-30    9
2     2015-10-31   10
      2015-11-30   10
      2015-12-31   10
      2016-01-31   11
      2016-02-28   11
      2016-03-31   11
      2016-04-30   12
      2016-05-31   12
      2016-06-30   12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create new groups `g1` with compare difference per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) for consecutive quarters, here 100 days (3 months) and also added 3 days for next month days:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['date'] = df['date'] + pd.Timedelta(3, unit='d')
df['g1'] = df.groupby('group')['date'].diff().dt.days.gt(100).cumsum()
```

Then is necessary add helper `DataFrame` with last duplicates values and datetimes with next 2 months for avoid only one last rows:

```
last = (df.drop_duplicates(['group','g1'], keep='last')
          .assign(date = lambda x: x['date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=2)))
print (last)
   group       date  var  g1
3      1 2010-12-03    7   0
5      1 2014-09-03    9   1
8      2 2016-06-02   12   1
```

Join to original and use [`DataFrameGroupBy.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html):

```
df = (pd.concat([df, last])
        .set_index('date')
        .groupby(['group', 'g1'])['var']
        .resample('m')
        .ffill()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))
```

---

```
print(df)
group  date      
1      2010-01-31     4
       2010-02-28     4
       2010-03-31     4
       2010-04-30     5
       2010-05-31     5
       2010-06-30     5
       2010-07-31     6
       2010-08-31     6
       2010-09-30     6
       2010-10-31     7
       2010-11-30     7
       2010-12-31     7
       2014-04-30     8
       2014-05-31     8
       2014-06-30     8
       2014-07-31     9
       2014-08-31     9
       2014-09-30     9
2      2015-10-31    10
       2015-11-30    10
       2015-12-31    10
       2016-01-31    11
       2016-02-29    11
       2016-03-31    11
       2016-04-30    12
       2016-05-31    12
       2016-06-30    12
Name: var, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping there is a more off-the-shelf solution, but it does what I am looking for. I presume that (a) you call `pd.Timedelta(3, unit='d')` with 3 to make sure the shifted `datetime` ends up in the next month (and not accidentally in the same month), (b) that `resample('M')` is [by definition](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) end of month and (c) that you call `gt(100)` because no quarter has more than 100 days so that it will pick up any gap in the quarterly series?!

Comment: @Jhonny - hmmm, if change `b` with `c` step then get more rows like need for resample, so used `c` and last `b` step.

Comment: Yes, I understand. My comment was not meant to reflect the order to the procedure. Rather, it raised questions about the logic of individual steps.